# RPi shutting down after powered from 5V pin

Tags: power-supply, power, usb-power, alternative-power

My RPi is working fine and automatically connecting to wifi when powered from USB but when I try to power it from a regulated 5V supply on the extension headers I can see that it goes on but then short after a while the wifi dongle's light goes off and I never get a chance to even ssh in. When I powered it from usb again it works completely fine. Any idea what could be causing it and what I can do about it?

PS. The 5V is regulated from a 12V open frame power supply and seems to be a very solid supply.

Comment: Seems like the 5V isn't stable enough. What are you using to convert the 12V to 5V?

Comment: I am using a normal 7805 regulator but with 2 10uF capacitors only on the 12V input. Should I add some on the 5V output?

Comment: Definitely. The datasheet suggest adding a 0.1uF to the output and .33uF to the input (http://www.sminntech.com/images/7805datasheet.gif). I'd try also adding a electrolytic cap, something like 10uF.

Comment: I'll give it a try tomorrow and see if it helps

Comment: Hello Gerharddc, did you solve the issue? Please feel free to share your experience by writing your own answer.